# why phppgadmin just display php code?

Tags: php, linux, postgresql, phppgadmin

I following this tutorial
[How To Install phpPgAdmin on Debian 9 / Ubuntu 16.04 / LinuxMint 18](http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/debian/how-to-install-phppgadmin-on-debian-9-ubuntu-16-04-linuxmint-18.html)
. but when I finish phppgadmin not display, even just show this `

```
/**
 * Main access point to the app.
 *
 * $Id: index.php,v 1.13 2007/04/18 14:08:48 mr-russ Exp $
 */

// Include application functions
$_no_db_connection = true;
include_once('./libraries/lib.inc.php');
$misc->printHeader('', null, true);

$rtl = (strcasecmp($lang['applangdir'], 'rtl') == 0);

$cols = $rtl ? '*,'.$conf['left_width'] : $conf['left_width'].',*';
$mainframe = '<frame src="intro.php" name="detail" id="detail" frameborder="0" />?><frameset cols="<?php echo $cols ?>"><?php if ($rtl) echo $mainframe; ?>

<frame src="browser.php" name="browser" id="browser" frameborder="0" /><?php if (!$rtl) echo $mainframe; ?>

<noframes>
<body>
    <?php echo $lang['strnoframes'] ?><br />
    <a href="intro.php"><?php echo $lang['strnoframeslink'] ?></a>
</body>
</noframes></frameset><?php $misc->printFooter(false);?>
```

please tell me why and how I fixed that.

thanks.

Comment: check your `$mainframe` variable. You mixed `?>` and `<?php` with existing php code. Have you set an `<?php ` at your file beginning?

Answer (score -1):

After installing Apache, open the file:

```
sudo **yourEditor** /etc/apache2/apache.conf
```

and add this line on the botton:

```
#phpMyAdmin Configuration
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Finally, restart apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Now you can get phpMyAdmin working on http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin.

Comment: my phpmyadmin is working, this is phppgadmin for postgresql problem.